# How to export shape keys as fbx when they are controlled by drivers?

Tags: drivers, shape-keys, .fbx

Good afternoon,

I have an animation set up in Blender where I have bones controlling the shape keys of my object. The shape keys have drivers, so when my bones move, the shape keys activate. However, when I export this as an fbx file into Unity, none of my shape keys are observable. How can I export this as an fbx?

Comment: Hoi Luis, This is exactly what i want to achieve. Have you found a solution?